# Understanding SyntaxError from PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis

I'm using QGIS 2.18.16 and following the training [manual](https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/pdf/en/QGIS-2.14-QGISTrainingManual-en.pdf), and I'm stuck on 6.4.5.

I've followed the example to produce an action that will search wiki, but I receive a syntax error as listed below:

```
An error occurred during execution of the following code:
from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl; from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebView; myWV = QWebView(None); myWV.load(QUrl(’http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Swellendam’)); myWV.show()


  File "", line 1
    from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl; from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebView; myWV = QWebView(None); myWV.load(QUrl(’http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Swellendam’)); myWV.show()
                                                                                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

The code:  from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl; from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebView; myWV = QWebView(None); myWV.load(QUrl(’http://wikipedia.org/wiki/[% "name" %]’)); myWV.show()
```

Any thoughts on where I've gone wrong?

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: Don't put multiple python statements on the same line separated by semicolons - makes it *much* harder to see what line the mistake is.

Comment: Perhaps you should try testing it with the [2.18 Training Manual](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/pdf/en/QGIS-2.18-QGISTrainingManual-en.pdf) instead of 2.14. There may have been changes to the Python API between those versions.

Comment: I think its your quotation marks.You seem to not be using proper single quote marks. You should use `'` marks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your single quote marks are the wrong sort of quote mark. This is using quotes cut and pasted from your code:

```
s = ’http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Swellendam’

  File "<stdin>", line 1
    s = ’http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Swellendam’
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

And this is using single quotes from my keyboard:

```
s = 'http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Swellendam'
```

no syntax error.

Comment: Cheers, simple stuff really! Thanks for answering.